# Java 8 option can't be unselected in Codename One?

Tags: codenameone

A user of codename One meets this error:

```
Updating property file: C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Rim Karaki CV Mobile Apps\build\built-jar.properties

Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller

code size and wider device support

Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Rim Karaki CV Mobile Apps\build\tmp

javac: invalid target release: 1.8

Usage: javac <options> <source files>

use -help for a list of possible options

C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Rim Karaki CV Mobile Apps\build.xml:50: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I was advising to uncheck the "Java 8 project" setting at the creation stage of the project, but the user can't actually unselect the option:

[image]

I don't get it, what can be the issue here?

Comment: What Netbeans version is this? Is his/her Codename plugin and Java up-to-date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Chen already fixed that in our upcoming version. We'll try to release early next week.

As a workaround you can do one of the following:

- Install Java 8 and make sure NetBeans runs on it.
- Create a Java 8 project then remove the Java 8 build hint and change the project properties in the lib section to not use Java 8. Then fix the `build.xml` line 50 to have 1.5 instead of 1.8.